# Wordpress - changing logo when on an imember360 page

Tags: php, wordpress

A client is using iMember360 on his website, and doesn't want to give me access to the infusionsoft login so I can't ask this in their support forums, so hoping someone here will know a solution.

When you are viewing pages that are for a specific membership role only, he wants the website to have a different logo.

**IE .** if you are a profit.Ology member/subscriber, show a profit.Ology logo.

I was hoping when you are logged in, it would add some sort of body class to the tune of 'Profit.ology-Membership', so I could use that to change the logo, but nothing like that happens.

I know I can add a class using `body_class('$myclass');` - but my issue is I don't know how to grab a variable for which of these was clicked (if that makes sense).

[image]

Has anyone done this before? Any ideas?

---

Cookies...

[image]

Comment: Can you check cookies to see if cookies of varying names are made for different user types?

Comment: I've added an image of the cookies in my question above. The one highlighted looks like it might have something to do with imember360, as I've seen that plugin use the 'i4w' for other things. - However I only want to change the logo for the pages restricted by imember360, not the entire site based on if there is a cookie (if that's what you were thinking).

Comment: Well, I was thinking something along the lines of `if($_COOKIE['i4w_session'] == 'subscriber') echo 'logo1.jpg'; else echo 'logo2.jpg';` But it doesn't seem like that'd work in your situation.

Comment: not quite. I appreciate the suggestion however, I didn't think to look for a cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use the shortcodes provided by the iMember360 Wordpress plugin. [See here for a reference](http://docs.imember360.com/shortcodes/regular/). Even though it's not the original intent, you can use a shortcode as a php function (getting a value in return) by doing the following:

```
$variable = do_shortcode('[shortcode-name]');
```

So for example, if you used the ran the following code:

```
$i4w_users = do_shortcode('[i4w_user_levels sep="|"]');
```

Then take a look at what information is contained in the $i4w_users variable. You might be able to use that to parse out different user types/levels. If that shortcode doesn't do what you're looking for, you might need to look at some of the other shortcodes they provide on that reference page.

Comment: YES!!!! This is totally what I needed. The shortcode 'i4w_page_levels' spit out which of those boxes where checked off. Now I can add that to my body class and style away!